# React Native's Metro listens to localhost, should be it's external IP

Tags: android, react-native

The app that runs on my emulator tries to connect to 10.0.1.12:8081.
But my development server that started when I run `react-native run-android` listens to localhost:8081.
How do I fix this? Either by binding Metro to the correct interface or tell the app that runs on my emulator to connect to a different server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the natural behavior.
Are you trying to connect from an external device? 
If so, just open the **Dev Settings** menu, select **Dev Settings** -> **Debug server host & port for device**. Then you put your internal IP.